# Scroll to bottom of page with animation vb.net

Tags: jquery, css, vb.net, animation, scroll

I am trying to create a login page that will be accessed from mobiles and PCS. In the bottom of my form (which is approximately in the bottom of the page) I am displaying the label error. The problem is that on small devices when became visible, users cannot see it unless they scroll down the screen. So I tried to make an automatic scroll using jquery using below:

```
 $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#LabelError").offset().top }, 500);
```

This is working perfectly, but I need to make it from server side using vb.NET, but I don't know how. Any helps?

Answer (score 0):

You could register and use JS from VB.Net like:

Define a error div in html (Default.aspx or whatever):

```
<div id="ErrorDiv">Error</div>
```

Then from vb.net call it like

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "SetFocus", "window.location.hash = '#ErrorDiv';", True)
```

Click event example:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}#{1}", Request.RawUrl, "ErrorDiv"))
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript([GetType](), "SetFocus", "window.location.hash = '#ErrorDiv';", True)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. Thank you anyway

Comment: This code is tested and working fine on my system. check if there is some other error

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved it.
I handled the event when label is visible using jquery:

```
$(function () {

   var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
     $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $("#LabelError").offset().top }, 500);
     $("#LabelError").focus();
  });

  var target = document.querySelector('#LabelError');
  observer.observe(target, {
      attributes: true
  });

});
```